# Encrypt Environment variable and call it in the terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can I make the values of variables as secrets or access them as environment variables in Terraform?

For example, I am provisioning a data source resource, e.g.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora" {
    cluster_identifier            = var.db_cluster_identifier
    database_name                 = var.rds_db_name
    master_username               = var.rds_master_username
    master_password               = var.rds_master_password
    backup_retention_period       = var.backup_retention_period
    preferred_backup_window       = var.preferred_backup_window
    preferred_maintenance_window  = var.preferred_maintenance_window
    db_subnet_group_name          = aws_db_subnet_group.aurora.name
    #final_snapshot_identifier     = var.db_snapshot_cluster_identifier
    vpc_security_group_ids        = [aws_security_group.allow-aurora-db.id]
    skip_final_snapshot           = true
    # ...
}
```

In here, i have a parameter like:
master_password = var.rds_master_password

whose value I am getting as plain text stored in my “terraform.tfvars”, e.g.
rds_master_password = "myDBpwsddnn123"

My question is if I store the encoded value in the “terraform.tfvars”, is there any way I can decode it in my resource file?

I am using Bitbucket as my repo. I am using AWS Secrets Manager as a centralized repository for all the passwords  Then my question is how can I get the environment variable in my Terraform resource, any pointers?

Comment: Your question can be hard to understand. You have a value stored in a terraform.tfvars, you reference this value in your resource file. And If I understand right you want to instead of hardcoding the value in terraform.tfvars, you want to pass it with an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the terraform documentation that you can find here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html

The easiest way to pass an OS environment variable to your terraform you have to do :

First, you need to define your env variable in your terminal like this, you must add the prefix `TF_VAR_` to your variable name.

```sh
export TF_VAR_database_secret=<my_secret>
```

And then in your terraform code you could create your terraform variable that has the same name of the OS env variable without the `TF_VAR_` prefix.

```
variable "database_secret" {
    type = string
}
```

Then you can use the variable like you already did before like for example `var.database_secret`

Answer (score 0):

You can read thru [this comprehensive guide](https://blog.gruntwork.io/a-comprehensive-guide-to-managing-secrets-in-your-terraform-code-1d586955ace1) on dealing with secrets.

Like @severin.julien, personally I find `TF_VAR_` is easy to use.